# Do restrictions on port ranges exist for Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We run a SF standalone cluster (V6.5.641.9590) on windows 2016 nodes and have defined a application port range between 30001 and 30081. Occasionally we are facing port conflicts with SF internal services like image store service.

For a Service Fabric cluster, does there exists any range restrictions for application ports or ephemeral ports?. I have seen some posts mentioning that application ports have to be below 30000, but in the official documentation nothing alike is written.

Here is the snippet from the manifest:

```
<Endpoints>
    <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
    <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19002" />
    <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19001" />
    <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
    <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="http" />
    <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19003" />
    <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="30001" EndPort="30081" />
    <EphemeralEndpoints StartPort="29000" EndPort="30000" />
</Endpoints>
```

With this setting we have a conflicting service (ImageStore service from SF) running on port 30006/30007.

Comment: Did you make sure that application ports and ephemeral ports do not overlap? SF system services rely on the ephemeral port range to communicate. The port ranges are specified in the cluster manifest.

Comment: Our ranges do not overlap. I've added the manifest snipped in the post.